# Автоматизация действий в Telegram без юзероботов

Tags: telegram

Хотел поинтересоваться, возможно ли имитировать действия в Телеграм, не используя юзерботов?

Увидел где-то в интернете бота, который для работы требует просто авторизацию в аккаунт Telegram. Интересно, как создать такого?

Comment: У телеграма есть два разных API: 1) [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots) для создания ботов, 2) основной [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/#telegram-api), с помощью которого можно делать что угодно. Вам нужно изучать второй.

Comment: Я знаю,спрашиваю есть ли способы без апи,а напрямую имитировать действия пользователя

Comment: Напишите подробнее, что вы подразумеваете под "напрямую имитировать"? Использовать официальный API -- это как-то не напрямую?)